# Add a column to Django UserAdmin interface showing count in ForeignKey relationship?

Tags: django, django-admin

Each User of my Django admin has associated a number of Profiles. I want to display in the User table a column with a count of the number of Profiles associated with each User. How can I do this?

You can see the code for `Profile` Model here: http://codepad.org/9yLet9el.

Here is what I tried. The relevant portion of `admin.py` is:

```
def profile_count(self, user):
    return user.profiles.count()

class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = UserAdmin.list_display + 'profile_count'

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

But for some reason the User admin table stays the same. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Also, a peek at the models and ModelAdmin would be a huge help.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I tried defining `UserAdmin`, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33778645/855050). But it doesn't work. In general, all I want to do is to add a column to the table of users showing some additional information about the users.

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm I have defined a `Profile` model. The `Profile` model has a `ForeignKey` linking to `User`. It follows that each `Profile` is linked to a `User` (the same `User` can be linked to several `Profile`s). Now I want to add a column to the `User` table of the admin interface showing how many Profiles are linked to each user.

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm Find here the code I have for the `Profile` model. http://codepad.org/9yLet9el. If you need anything else let me know.

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm The `responsible` property (at the end) is the one that links to `User`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. Just add this to `admin.py`.

```
def profile_count(self, user):
    return user.profile_set.count()

UserAdmin.profile_count = profile_count
UserAdmin.list_display += ('profile_count',)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include callables in `list_display`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

So just write a function that—given a `User`—will return the number of profiles, for example:

```
def profile_count(user):
    return user.profiles.count()

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = [..., profile_count]
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could try putting `'profiles.count'` directly into `list_display`, but I doubt that'd work.

Comment: But won't this modify the whole UserAdmin table?

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. The user admin table doesn't change.